# How to compile Hello World program for PowerPC

Tags: c, gcc, powerpc

I have a Dreambox 500 which on Wikipedia says has a PCP processor which is PowerPC:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor: 0
cpu: STBx25xx
clock: 252MHz
Review: 9.80 (pvr 5151 0950)
bogomips: 250.36
Machine: Dream Multimedia Dreambox TV
plb bus clock: 63MHz
```

I would normally install GCC but it has low storage on it and I need to compile a program for it.

I've heard GCC can compile powerpc but I had no luck doing so.

Example this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

And I use this to compile

```
gcc example.c -mtune=powerpc
```

But it give this error

```
example.c:1:0 error: bad value (powerpc) for -mtune- switch
#include <stdio.h>
^
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being on a programming forum for a while, found a guy with the same problem, and after a while he found a way to fix it and I tried it and it works.
The thing I have to do is

```
powerpc-gcc someprog.c -static
```

I have no idea what the -static does but it increases the executable file size and at the end it works!

Comment: AFAIK the static flag compiles your binary to a monolithic executable that doesn't have run-time library dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

You should use cross-compiler, because your **target** architecture differs from **host** one. Host is the architecture of your system (usually `amd64` (x86_64) or `i386` (x86_32)). And target arch is the arch on which your compiled program will run (`powerpc` in your case).

Many GNU/Linux distors provide crosscompilers as a separate packages. For example, for Ubuntu these packages are available:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-powerpc-linux-gnu g++-4.8-powerpc-linux-gnu binutils-4.8-powerpc-linux-gnu
```

Packages above are for trusty. In later releases different GCC versions are available.

Then you can compile your program using `powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc-4.8`. Or you can set your environment variables `CC` and `CXX` to `powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc-4.8` and `powerpc-linux-gnu-g++-4.8` accordingly.

**upd:**
I found crosscompiler toolchain for Dreambox 500 [here](http://www.streamboard.tv/oscam/wiki/crosscompiling#dm500_ppc), but it contains relatively old GCC (3.4).

In order to use it extract downloaded file to `/opt/cross/dm500`, add `/opt/cross/dm500/cdk/bin` to path via `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/cross/dm500/cdk/bin` and use `gcc` from here with appropriate prefix.

Comment: Compiler isn't giving me error for now, gonna test it on my dm500.

Comment: When I run it, it says "Segmentation fault". :(

Comment: Run `ldd a.out` (or whatever name your compiled program has) and post here its output.

Comment: It says "not a dynamic executable".

Comment: Where are your running this?

Comment: Well, actually, you can try compiling with `-static-libgcc` flag.

Comment: I did the ldd test.out on my linux pc

Comment: Ok, then do `powerpc-linux-gnu-readelf -a test.out | grep "Shared library:"`. It should print all needed dynamic libraries.

Comment: I did
powerpc-linux-gnu-gcc-4.8 example.c -static-libgcc
But still segmentation fault.
What does segmentation fault mean anyway?

Comment: It says 0x0000001 (NEEDED)        Shared library: [libc.sp.6]

Comment: Your target system may use different libc (e.g. uclibc instead of glibc), so needed libs (like `libc.sp.6`) won't be found.